# Why is this function going in a loop?

Tags: c++, stamp

```
void listord::stmp()
{
    nodeL *aux=head;
    cout<<"STMP"<<endl;
    while (aux)
    {
        cout<<aux->getData();
        aux=aux->getNext();
    }
    cout<<endl;
    return;
}
```

I can't understand why this simply list print code loops. I know that it could be because of a bad pointer but i don't know how to solve it.

```
class nodeL{
    private:
        int data;
        nodeL *next;
    public:
        nodeL();
        nodeL(int d);
        nodeL(int d,nodeL *n);
        int getData();
        nodoL *getNext();
        void setData(int d);
        void setNext(nodeL *n);
};
```

This is the nodeL class, the `GetNext()` it's just a return next, nothing else.

Comment: I would say it's because `getNext()` returns a non-null pointer, but without seeing the code for that function it's tough to know what it's doing.

Comment: Do you initialize `next` anywhere in your constructors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to set `next = nullptr` in your constructor. Also you want to return `*&` from your getNext function, like this:

```
nodeL *& getNext();
```

These two things should fix your issue.